# How to store data from IoT machine on private Stardust tangle

Tags: hornet, shimmer, private-network

I have deployed a private Stardust network and I want to be able to store data from IoT machines on it, which is the most suitable transaction type to do this?

I am currently using Tagged Payload transaction type but my questions is how can I access to it from a different client - without knowing the Block ID of the transaction the data is encapsulated in?

And even more, how can I query within Tagged Payloads for specific data Tags or content? Having a look at the INX Indexer: https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iotaledger/tips/main/tips/TIP-0026/indexer-rest-api.yaml, this solution only allows to sort within different transactions, but it is not implemeted for Tagged Payloads.

I then tried to look in the IOTA Client library: https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/iota.rs/libraries/nodejs/references/classes/Client/#getblock, but again there are only implemented queries for Outputs, NFTs and Native Tokens value transactions.

I know there is an INX Collector project that works as an INX plugin for Hornet nodes that allows to store all blocks with a specific Tag, working as a selective permanode: https://github.com/teleconsys/inx-collector
However, this option implies to store all blocks locally which is not an optimal solution.

In this particular case, as working with a private Tangle there is no intention of implementing any type of prunning.

Answer (score 1):

You could also store data on the outputs by using the metadata feature described here:
https://github.com/iotaledger/tips/blob/main/tips/TIP-0018/tip-0018.md#metadata-feature
One can  index the  output by adding also a tag feature described here:
https://github.com/iotaledger/tips/blob/main/tips/TIP-0018/tip-0018.md#tag-feature
Then the other client can ask the inx indexer from outputs by tag
https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iotaledger/tips/main/tips/TIP-0026/indexer-rest-api.yaml

Now i see you also can use mqtt, I think previously this was not possible.
You could use `blocks/tagged-data/{tag}` from
[https://studio.asyncapi.com/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iotaledger/tips/main/tips/TIP-0028/event-api.yml#operation-subscribe-blocks/tagged-data/{tag}](https://studio.asyncapi.com/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iotaledger/tips/main/tips/TIP-0028/event-api.yml#operation-subscribe-blocks/tagged-data/%7Btag%7D)

*Credit goes to linaWhiteSen and Mesrine on the IOTA&Shimmer Discord*

Comment: Do you recommend using Outputs to store data in the Metadata field? As the main feature of my application is to share pure data I haven't thought before on this option. I guess I should then indicate that there is no actual token transfer and just request funds to the faceut for the storage deposit, right?
When it comes to MQTT subscription, this is a great option but not suitable if someone wants to retrieve the whole historic bunch of data a specific client has stored on the Tangle.

Credit goes to linaWhiteSen on the IOTA&Shimmer Discord

Comment: I will prefer to use the metadata feature of the outputs. Yes you just have to pay for the storage deposit.


Credit goes to Mesrine on the IOTA&Shimmer Discord